# How to assign a value to a reference?

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to make a roguelike in java to practice. This is my code to generate a floor (right now just a big room with wall tiles on the edge). I'm trying to set certain tiles in my tile array to either a wall tile or floor tile. Although when they leave the setTile method, they revert back to their value before entering the method. I'm going insane. Here's my code:

```
public Floor(int width, int height) {
        this.tiles = new Tile[(width+1)*(height+1)];
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        generateTiles();    
        boolean test = false;
    }
    public Tile getTile(int x, int y)
    {
        return tiles[y * width + x];
    }

    public void setTile(int x, int y, Tile tile)
    {
        Tile tileToSet = getTile(x,y);
        tileToSet = tile;
    }
    private void generateTiles() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++)
        {
            tiles[i] = new Tile();
        }
        //make the top wall
        for (int i = 0; i<width;i++)
        {
            setTile(i,0,new WallTile());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is **call by value**. But ... even that doesn't explain your code, or what you're asking, now  that I look at it.

Comment: and your question is...?

Comment: What is `setTile` supposed to do? All it does is assign something to a local variable

Comment: How do I set a "tile" in that array to a new instance? @BrianRoach I am trying to wrap my head around that. Instead of using getTile to return a tile and then create a new instance to that reference, do I need to get the index in the array and then update it with something like tiles[getTile(x,y)] = new WallTile();? Sorry, I code mostly in c# and you can do these types of things.

Comment: @MiserableVariable setTile is supposed to use getTile to find the index of a tile (based on it's xy) and then update that instance with a different Tile class instance (be it a WallTile or FloorTile, which both extends Tile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setTile` doesn't make sense. You're *retrieving* the tile which is currently at that position, storing it in a *local variable* `tileToSet` and then *overwriting* the value of that variable.

What you're *trying* to do is storing the given tile in the `tiles` array. Analogous to how `getTile` is implemented, you can do this with:

```
public void setTile(int x, int y, Tile tile)
{
    tiles[y * width + x] = tile;
}
```

Note that this is *not* equivalent (but you seem to think it is) with:

```
public void setTile(int x, int y, Tile tile)
{
    Tile tileToSet = tiles[y * width + x];
    tileToSet = tile;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so anything that is returned from getTile is only a value not a reference, so updating that value is worthless as when it exits the method it disappears, but the way you wrote it updates the actual array element? What if I wanted to do more things to the tile I'm setting? Would I have to put tiles[y * width + x] in each statement or that method?

Comment: @stereoa No, you just need to make sure `tiles[y * width + x]` is on the left hand of the assignment when you need to store it in the array. The right hand side can be any `Tile` you want: a parameter, a local variable you processed,...

Comment: `int tileToSet = y * width + x;`
`tiles[tileToSet] = tile;`
`tiles[tileToSet].x = x;`
`tiles[tileToSet].y = y;` Would these be correct?

Comment: @stereoa That'll work, but you have to ask yourself a few questions. Does the `tile` passed in as argument need to remain unmodified? If no, then no problem, just adjust the `x` and `y` fields and store the modified `tile` in the array. Otherwise, you'll need to somehow clone the tile in order to keep the original `tile` intact and instead modify and store the clone. This (im)mutability decision is a choice that should fit in your overall design.

Answer (score 1):

This code is setting the same variable twice and doing nothing with it.

```
 public void setTile(int x, int y, Tile tile)
    {
        Tile tileToSet = getTile(x,y);
        tileToSet = tile;
    }
```

I think you want something like this:

```
 public void setTile(int x, int y, Tile tile)
    {
        tiles[y * width + x] = tile;
    }
```

That would change the value of what is stored in the tiles array to the supplied Tile object.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `setTile` method:

```
public void setTile(int x, int y, Tile tile)
{
    Tile tileToSet = getTile(x,y);
    tileToSet = tile;
}
```

You are getting the tile value at x,y and set it to a local variable (`tileToSet`), then set the `tile` value to the variable `tileToSet`. Of course it doesn't change the tile at x,y. `tileToSet` is just a reference to the value, **it is never a reference to the array element**.

replace with this:

```
public void setTile(int x, int y, Tile tile)
{
    tiles[y * width + x] = tile;
}
```

and if you want to have a method that returns tile **index**, like you said in your command, you can rewrite the get/set pair like this:

```
public void setTile(int x, int y, Tile tile)
{
    tiles[getTileIndex(x, y)] = tile;
}

public Tile getTile(int x, int y)
{
    tiles[getTileIndex(x, y)] = tile;
}

public int getTileIndex(int x, int y)
{
    return y * width + x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ya in Java when you pass an object into the function, the reference to that object is copied by value. What this means is you can't swap tile references.

What you'll need to do, is something like this:

```
public Floor(int width, int height) {
        this.tiles = new Tile[(width+1)*(height+1)];
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        generateTiles();    
        boolean test = false;
    }
    public Tile getTile(int x, int y)
    {
        return tiles[y * width + x];
    }

    public void setTile(int x, int y, Tile tile)
    {

        tiles[y * width + x] = tile;//this works cuz it takes the ref from the array and assigns it the copy of the reference passed in

    }
    private void generateTiles() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++)
        {
            tiles[i] = new Tile();
        }
        //make the top wall
        for (int i = 0; i<width;i++)
        {
            setTile(i,0,new WallTile());
        }
    }
}
```

Check out this article for explanation: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html

Comment: Thank you for the article. It is helping me wrap my brain around it. I've been coding in c# for too long and I feel spoiled. At first run, I still dislike pass by value, but I will adapt :D

Comment: I believe it works the same in C# unless you use the ref keyword

Comment: see this for c# explanation http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html#value